# HasOne relation form doesn't update model

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I extends model `Lovata\Buddies\User` adding `vendor` relation. From backend form, I can create a new Vendor model and field `commission` is added fine. But if I update field value, the process show all fine, but the record is never updated in db. There is no error or exception.

[image]

```php
User::extend(
    function ($obModel) {
        /** @var User $obModel */
        $obModel->hasOne['vendor'] = [Vendor::class];
    }
);
```

#### Vendor model has BelongsTo relation to User model

```php
    public $belongsTo = [
        'user' => [User::class]
    ];
```

#### Users controller relation config

```yaml
vendor:
    label: 'planetadeleste.vendorsshopaholic::lang.label.name'
    manage:
        form: $/planetadeleste/vendorsshopaholic/models/vendor/fields.yaml
        list: $/planetadeleste/vendorsshopaholic/models/vendor/columns.yaml
    view:
        form: $/planetadeleste/vendorsshopaholic/models/vendor/fields.yaml
        toolbarButtons: update|delete
```

#### Vendor fields

```yaml
fields:
    commission:
        label: 'planetadeleste.vendorsshopaholic::lang.label.commission'
        span: left
```

Comment: I've got same problem, do you still finding solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `user_id` field to your Vendor DB table.

ref. https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#one-to-one

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I have it.

```sql
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
`commission` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Its bug in october core:
Just change line 1160 in `modules\backend\behaviors\RelationController.php`

Line 1160:

```
$this->viewModel = $this->manageWidget->model;
```

to this:

```
// Ensure that the view widget model is the same instance as the manage widget model
// since they will technically be different object instances in this context as
// $viewWidget->model is populated by $this->relationModel->getResults() and
// $manageWidget->model is populated by $this->relationModel->find($manageId);
$this->viewModel = $this->viewWidget->model = $this->manageWidget->model;
```